# String cannot be converted to ArrayList<String> Error

Tags: java, arraylist

Here is a program similar to the sinking battleship game from the book head first java. After compiling I am getting the error: "String cannot be converted to ArrayList Error" and ^ pointer point to the line I have two different files one with the main method and other a separate class. Whats wrong here.

Main method class

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class SimpleDotComTestDrive{

   public static void main(String[] args){

      SimpleDotCom dot=new SimpleDotCom();
      boolean repeat=false;
      String[] locations={"2","3","4"};
      dot.setLocationCells(locations);   //^ where compiler points the error
      Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.println("Lets Start");

      while(repeat==false) {
         System.out.println("Type your guess");
         String userGuess=input.nextLine();
         String result=dot.checkYourSelf(userGuess);
         System.out.println(result);

         if(result=="kill") {
            repeat=true;
            break;
         }
      }
   } //close main
} //close test class
```

Separately saved class which is part of this program:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class SimpleDotCom {
   private ArrayList<String>locationCells;

   public void setLocationCells(ArrayList<String> locs) {
      locationCells=locs;
   }

   public String checkYourSelf(String userGuess) {
      String result="miss";
      int index = locationCells.indexOf(userGuess);
      if(index>=0) { 
         locationCells.remove(index);

         if(locationCells.isEmpty()) {
            result="kill";
         }
         else {
            result="hit";
         }
    }
    return result;
  } //close check yourself method
} //close simple class
```

Comment: An array and an ArrayList are different things

Comment: `setLocationCells` takes an `ArrayList` but you are passing an array.

Comment: You are trying to set the List = "String" (or similar) while the "String" is not a List, so can not be assigned to it, only added to it as an element, using the .add("String") method

Comment: try : `Arrays.asList(locations)`

Answer (score 2):

You are getting the error because `setLocationCells()` method accepts an `ArrayList<String>` and you are passing it a String Array by doing:

```
dot.setLocationCells(locations);
```

You should either replace your method to accept `String[]` instead of `ArrayList<String>` or change your code as follows:

```
dot.setLocationCells(new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(locations));
```

Comment: You don't actually need the `String` - the type can be inferred by the diamond operator.

Comment: @Andy Turner Yes, I agree. `new ArrayList<>(...)` will work. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have `String[] locations={"2","3","4"};` and then parse it to the method `setLocationCells(ArrayList<String> locs){` that requires the `ArrayList`.

So, there are more ways:

1. Convert the array to list with: `new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(locations);`
2. Define the ArrayList instead:

   ```
   ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>() {{
       add("2");
       add("3");
       add("4");
   }};
   ```
3. Change your method at all:

   ```
   public void setLocationCells(String[] locs){
       Collections.addAll(locationcells, locs);
   }
   ```

Comment: 3. Not quite. Although the simple class name of the return value of `Arrays.asList` is `ArrayList`, it's actually `java.util.Arrays.ArrayList` rather than `java.util.ArrayList`. You'd need to copy it into a new `ArrayList`, as in 1.

Comment: 2. That's not valid Java.

Comment: I have tried change my method to: public void setLocationCells(String[] locs){
    locationCells=Arrays.asList(locs);
} but now getting cant find symbol ^Variable Arrays error